# Limit regex to exactly three characters

Tags: regex

My regex looks like this:

```
^[1-3][\/\][1-3]+$|-
```

It allows 
`1/3`, `2/3`, `2/-` so far so good. Unfortunately `3/3/3` is also valid. I tried to limit it like this:

```
^[1-3][\/\][1-3]{0,2}$|-
```

which does not work as expected.

How can I allow only three characters where first and last can either be a number from 1 to 3 or `-` and the second has to be a slash?

**Edit** I wrote the wrong range it´s not 1-9 but 1-3

Comment: Would `1\3` also be valid?

Answer (score 1):

I think `^[1-9-]/[1-9-]$` is what you want!

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF6tB4/1)

Comment: OP's range is `1-3`, not `1-9`, and in most cases you'll need to escape the `/`.

Comment: @Mathletics OP's not consistent in describing the range: his expression uses 1-3, yet the question mentions "from 1 to 9".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
^[1-9]\/[1-9-]$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cJ5pY2/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[0-9-]` to match "a number from 1 to 9, or `'-'`". The overall expression would look like this:

```
^[0-9-][\/][0-9-]$
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/pJ8nQ1/1)

Note that the dash is placed at the end of the *character class*. This is important, because a dash in the middle is interpreted as a character range.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for: (Numbers from 1 to 3 and minus acceptable in first and third location with a "/" between them)

```
^[1-3-]\/[1-3-]$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aC0gX8/1)